# Having a strange behavior with Ternary Logic

Tags: php, ternary-operator

When I do -

```
echo "Hello ". (true) ? 'World' : 'XYZ';
```

The output - `World` instead of `Hello World`. But when -

```
$person = (true) ? 'World' : 'XYZ';
echo  "Hello ".$person;
```

The output - `Hello World` which is expected. 
Don't understand why this behave like this! Is it expected?

Comment: I assume the `"Hello "` part is considered part of the condition

Comment: But it should not be i think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo "Hello ". (true) ? 'World' : 'XYZ';
```

is same as

```
echo ("Hello ". (true)) ? 'World' : 'XYZ';
```

You need:

```
echo "Hello ". (true ? 'World' : 'XYZ');
```

Comment: That means it is happening because of the operator precedence?

Comment: Yes it is because of precedence.

Comment: Ohk. Got the point. Thnx.